# Getting the value of id in node js

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am new on node js, I have this enterview question:
Let´s consider the following code snippet:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Hello ', + ???)
})

app.listen(300)

What you would replace ??? with to get the value of :id?
```

If you can help me with this and give an url to continue learning would be great.

Comment: Any Express tutorial, or the Express docs, will cover this.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for [routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).

Answer (score 1):

`:id` is a path parameter.

To access this in Express routes, you will use the following,

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Hello ', + req.params.id)
})

app.listen(300)
```

Comment: Check out this tutorial(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8bbbcskNkM&t=1s) for more information on Express routing and how you can use path parameters.